# Angular 4 Meta: add http-equiv dynamically

Tags: angular, meta

Using Angular 4(5),
I am trying to add a meta tag dynamically, specifically this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

So in Angular, I am doing this:

```
constructor(private meta: Meta) {
    this.meta.addTag({ httpEquiv: 'X-UA-Compatible', content: 'IE=edge' });
}
```

However, the above renders 'http-equiv' NOT hyphenated, like this:

```
<meta httpequiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

How do I get Angular to render the proper http-equiv meta tag attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

```
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'http-equiv', content: 'IE=edge' });
```

Answer (score 3):

*try this*

```
this.meta.addTag({'http-Equiv': 'X-UA-Compatible', content: "IE=edge"});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the proper way is:

```
meta.addTag({httpEquiv: 'Content-Type', content: 'text/html'});
```

https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-meta-service-for-meta-tags