# Angular SEO meta tag "http-equiv" and "httpequiv" are they the same?

Tags: angular, typescript, meta-tags

I am using Angular 7 project and I want to set my meta tag

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
```

dynamically. So I am trying to use the angular `platform-browser`

```
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

from the original document of Angular. Then I start typing like:

```
constructor(private meta: Meta) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.meta.updateTag({
    httpEquiv: 'content-language', content: this.activeLang
  });
}
```

It really does update my tag but it shows a bit different from the default:
The default `http-equiv`

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
```

After update

```html
<meta httpequiv="content-language" content="en">
```

My question: **Are they the same?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.meta.addTag({
  'http-Equiv': 'content-language',
  'content': this.activeLang
});
```

Reference: [Angular 4 Meta: add http-equiv dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672444/angular-4-meta-add-http-equiv-dynamically)

Comment: Thank you, that worked but I still wanted to know why Angular provide `httpEquiv` rather than `http-equiv`?

Comment: I think it's a bug in angular. Please check this open github issue - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31525